# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am using Posgres and I am using a mutator to get a value stored in a jsonb column. The mutator in an eloquent model:

Anuncios.php (model)

```
public function getStatusAttribute(){

   if( $this->attributes['marketplace_id'] === 2)
   {
        $json_marketplace = json_decode( $this->attributes['json_anuncio_marketplace']);


        return $json_marketplace->Code ;

   }

}
```

But I am getting the following error when retrieving the records from the Database, Anuncio::all();

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__toString() must not
>   throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Trying to get property
>   'Code' of non-object

What's going on?

Comment: Your `$this->attributes['json_anuncio_marketplace']` included not correct json and `json_decode` returned not correct `stdClass`-object

Comment: Using dd( $json_marketplace->Code) I can see the value.

Comment: If I just return a static value it works, return "943934" or return 39043943. I can also echo $json_marketplace->Code.

Comment: What means "static value"? If you check `dd` in the loop, you only see first element in the array.